# Laravel - How to search for specific field that is encrypted

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, laravel-5.3

i use laravel 5.3. Some fields are encrypted in the database using Crypt facade and encypt / decrypt
For updating or adding a row i need to check if a specific field that is encrypted, exists.
The table has thousands of rows and i cannot decrypt every row, it will take too much time.
Is there any solution on this rather than doing a foreach statement to search all the table rows one by one?

Comment: Search with a crypted key-value

Comment: Don't encrypt fields that you need to search. If you need it encrypted but still need something searchable, create a hash field that you can search against.

Comment: If your encryption returns the same crypto data for the same plain data, then you can simply create a unique index on the field, encrypt the data and try to insert it. The unique index will block the insertion attempt because the crypto texts match. If this is not the case, then do as @aynber suggested: create a separate hash key that is the same for the same plain text input and create the unique index on this hash to prevent duplicates.

Comment: So you mean to add a new field that this value will be hashed and search for the hashed value instead of the encrypted field?